# How can I 'select to end of file' in Notepad?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad, selection

Temporarily stuck with Notepad, I'd like to know if there is any better or quicker way of selecting from here to the end of the file than moving the mouse to the bottom of the screen and then vigorously from side to side (which is more exercise than I expect to get at a computer).

Comment: Did you try the "End" button and "Ctrl"+"End"?

Comment: All of my exercise comes from a computer so I better take what little I can find (:

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Place the cursor at the start of your selection then:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

To select to the end of notepad.

Comment: Thanks, Phydaux. It would never have entered my head to try that.

Comment: @Brian Hooper, no problem. It's a fairly ubiquitous keyboard short cut. Ctrl + Shift + Home will take you to the start too.

Comment: To elaborate, End alone means go to the end of the line, Ctrl+End means go to the end of the line. Adding Shift to the mix selects along the way (as it would with just Shift and arrow keys or even the mouse)

Comment: @Alex I think you mean "file" in your second sentence ;) @Brian it works with other combinations of Ctrl and Shift, too. Ctrl+Right will move along words, for example. Holding Shift while making movements will select the text that you are moving over. Ctrl+Shift+Right will select a word at a time. Shift+PgDown will select from the current cursor position down a page. Play around with it.

Comment: @Corey: Maybe ;)

Comment: On my laptop, where end is doubled on the right arrow key instead,  I additionally needed `fn` key for end of file.

Comment: Works with Notepad++ as well

Answer (score 2):

FYI in OSX you have to use the alternative key command like so:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + →

This arose when I was remote desktoping into a Windows 2000 server from my OSX laptop.

Comment: I think this is a bit irrelevant to this question, unless you want to post the possible combinations for all computer systems :)

Comment: @leinad13 - I would typically not do this, but wasn't finding results when I googled, hence why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word on Mac, it took me several tries but this worked:

Shft + Fn + Cmd + Right Arrow

...to select to end of file and delete.

Comment: The question doesn't mention a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it is simpler.

1. Place your cursor where you want to begin selection.
2. Go to this line and press Context Menu (right-click-mouse)|Begin/End Selection. Nothing is visually indicated but don't worry, selection start has been set.
3. Go to the line in the text where you want your selection to end and again press Context Menu|Begin/End Selection. The text block is now selected and this is visually indicated.
4. Do whatever you need with the text block.

Comment: It seems to me that Ctrl + Sift + End is simpler.